# to use calibri style for mac,ios,linux

Tags: ios, css, linux, font-family

As the calibri style is there in the Windows O.S but the calibri style is not there in the linux,mac,ios.If my project is having its style only in calibri(and I strickly have to use it)so if the user using the linux and run my project then my look of the project will change and if I copy/install the calibri in my linux it will be shown on my system only.I have done that in the war folder of my project I copy the calibri in ttf,otf,eot,woff form but still no change.So what should I do to use the calibri style for all the O.S.The css I used.

```
   .pop
    {
            border:1px solid black ;
            width:500px;
            height:140px;
            background-color: #d1d4d5;
            position:absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            cursor:pointer;
            font-family:calibri;
    }   


  public static native void hello()
 /*-{
        var body=$doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
         var popuptext=$doc.createTextNode(".......");
         popup.className="pop";
         popup.appendChild(popuptext);
 }-*/;
```

Comment: *I copy the calibri in ttf,otf,eot,woff form but still no change*: please provide the code you've used to embed the font

Comment: I have also add the calibri style in the war/lib folder of my but on change I simply copy and paste the calibri style in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use Calibri font in linux and mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492502/how-to-use-calibri-font-in-linux-and-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the calibri font in your system then you've to upload the font on the server and then provide the path in CSS. ofcourse you need different type format so font render perfectly on all browser.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Calibri', Fallback, sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  src: url('Calibri.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('Calibri.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('Calibri.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('Calibri.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('Calibri.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: how can I upload the font in the server

Comment: if you have the font then as you upload the images and file on server same way have to upload the font file also. and after that provide full path for font in above css code.

Comment: please clear my doubt in my css how can I use both the font-family and font-face

Comment: Using `@font-face` you can use custom font in website or in web project. and then using `font-family` you have to called that font style.

Comment: @KheemaPandey What fallback font would you use for Calibri?

Answer (score 0):

Use @font-face for your css.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Calibri";
 src: url("url of font file");
}
```

Comment: and you will required font in following format to work in all browser. `ttf,otf,eot,woff`

Comment: where the url of the font the get from.I think that calibri is not free to use

Comment: it is the path in which you copied the font. Copying the file isn't enough, you also need to specify in the css where is the font, aka "embed".